# Understanding "Invalid read of size n"

Tags: c, valgrind

I have read a couple of threads about this Valgrind error, most of them give localised responses.  I would like to know exactly what is wrong so that I can debug these errors in the future myself.

I will only post the relevant code, If anyone wants more I will post that too..

So I have an `Invalid read of size 4` on this line:

```
int t = (p->acts+p->ac)->time;
```

Note the pointer arithmetic which I think might be involved in the error??

I get the same error on this line, accessing the same member:

```
next->time = next->acts[next->ac].time;
```

How do I approach debugging this.. the program runs fine but I want to know what is going on.

Please comment if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

That error would indicate that `next->ac` (`p->ac`) is a value past the end of the memory allocated to `next->acts` (`p->acts`)

i.e...

```
next->acts = malloc( sizeof( something ) * count );
next->ac = count;

next>acts[next->ac].time = 0;
```

This would throw the error because `count` as an array index is actually one past the size of the array (base zero and all that)

Put another way, `next->ac >= count` would throw that error in the example I give.

Your program **may** work correctly because accessing past the end of allocated memory is undefined behavior. It could work, or it could spontaneously result in who knows what mayhem. But, all the same, accessing past the end of the allocated memory is an error.

Comment: Or that `next->acts` has been released back to the runtime and, though the dereference still "works" it is undefined behavior. Either way, its bad.

Comment: Interesting that this doesn't cause a seg fault then!?

Comment: It likely will not cause a SIGSEGV because it **is** (or was) a valid pointer. The undefined behavior is that you have no idea what the memory you're accessing is being used for (you don't own it and have no idea if anything else does or if the memory is being used at all). The undefined nature is what the consequences of manipulating it may be... keep in mind that writing past the end of buffers is a common hacker technique (though typically they're targeting stack variables in doing that)